# To solve $ \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve the differential equation $ \dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ ?

Comment: Where did you take this problem ? I am just curious : so simple differential equation leading (to me, at least) to a real nightmare !

Comment: The solution has to be approximated numerically I guess. Wolfram Differential Equations does not provide a closed form.

Comment: This is equivalent to $x'(y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: $x(y)$ grows at least as fast as exponential, since distance to origin is no less than distance from axis.  Eventually the y value will be so much less than the x value that asymptotically it should behave like $x = e^y$ or so, no?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Every truly nonlinear ODE is a real nightmare. Let me suggest you one more example: $y''=y^2+x$. If you find even one particular solution analytically, this would be an extremely significant mathematical result.

Comment: @DanielV Similarly $y(x)$ grows more slowly than $\ln(x)$, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: And adding to my last comment, if we have established that $y<c\ln(x)$ for large $x$, then we can conclude that $\frac{dy}{dx}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+c^2\ln(x)^2}}>\frac{1}{x+c\ln(x)}>\frac{1}{c x \ln(x)}$, so $y$ grows faster than $\ln(\ln(x))$. That is, for large enough $x$, $c_1\ln(x)>y>c_2\ln(\ln(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

Since this problem is not amenable to the standard repertoire of 1st order techniques, we might use some asymptotic analysis to understand the qualitative features of this ODE. Firstly, the derivative is always positive and bounded as $x$ or $y$ or both approach $\pm\infty$. The limiting differential equation in all of these cases is $y'=0$. And so in the asymptotic behavior is constant. On the other hand, the origin is a singularity and so we might ask what is the behavior near $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Suppose we investigate $y=c\sqrt{x}$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$ near the origin. Then the differential equation near the origin becomes $y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+c^2x}}\approx\frac{1}{c\sqrt{x}}$ and so $y(x)\approx \sqrt{x}/c$ and we see this matches our supposition up to a multiplicative constant. If we suppose that $y = cx^r$ near the origin and go through the same argument we find that $r=1/2$ necessarily. So the asymptotic behavior near the origin goes as the square root.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Apply the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

Let $u=x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{y^2}{2u}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{y}{u}$

$\therefore\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{y}{u}=u-\left(\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{y^2}{2u}\right)$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{y}{u}=\dfrac{u}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2u}$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{y^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{u}{2}+\dfrac{y^2+2y}{2u}$

$(u^2+y^2)\dfrac{du}{dy}=u^3+(y^2+2y)u$

Let $v=u^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dy}=2u\dfrac{du}{dy}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u^2+y^2}{2u}\dfrac{dv}{dy}=u^3+(y^2+2y)u$

$(u^2+y^2)\dfrac{dv}{dy}=2u^4+(2y^2+4y)u^2$

$(v+y^2)\dfrac{dv}{dy}=2v^2+(2y^2+4y)v$

Let $w=v+y^2$ ,

Then $v=w-y^2$

$\dfrac{dv}{dy}=\dfrac{dw}{dy}-2y$

$\therefore w\left(\dfrac{dw}{dy}-2y\right)=2(w-y^2)^2+(2y^2+4y)(w-y^2)$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dy}-2yw=2w^2+(4y-2y^2)w-4y^3$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dy}=2w^2+(6y-2y^2)w-4y^3$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $w=\dfrac{1}{z}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{dy}=-\dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{dz}{dy}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{z^3}\dfrac{dz}{dy}=\dfrac{2}{z^2}+\dfrac{6y-2y^2}{z}-4y^3$

$\dfrac{dz}{dy}=4y^3z^3+(2y^2-6y)z^2-2z$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the conclusion. Have you managed to find the general solution? If yes, could you please write it down explicitly?

Comment: I think OP should be a warned that before trying the method (which in this case will be very complicated and messy) that it is very unlikely that the Abel equation you end up with has a nice (or any) elementary solution. One indication of this (but does not prove anything) is that none of the best mathematical software packages (Mathematica, Maple) we have today is unable to solve it.

Comment: Consider a substitution such as $x=y tan(u)$ as suggested by Symbolab web site.