# $dy/dx=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

slope=distance from origin, should be simple and interesting. May have no solution!

I have tried several approaches, **best**:

$(\frac{dy}{dx}-y)(\frac{dy}{dx}+y)=x^2$  multiply by $e(-x) * e(+x)$ as integrating factor. Substitute $\frac{1}{2}x^2=t$.

**Second approach:**

$y=x\sinh(u)$ and $x=e(t)$ yields $\frac{du}{dt} + \tanh(u)=e(t)$.

Sorry, I am not yet using the proper format.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You should be able to get the first few terms in $y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots$ with all the $a_i$ functions of $a_0$.

Comment: Perhaps convert to polar coordinates?

Comment: Mathematica does not find an explicit solution. Probably there is no solution in terms of elementary (or even special) functions.

Comment: When $y$ is  much bigger than $x$, it is roughly $dy/dx=|y|\implies y=A\exp\pm x$

Comment: Yes, all tried so far. Polar coordinates don't help. Power series approach didn't yield result. Once y>x, then dy/dx=sqrt(2) * Y yields upward bound of y=exp(sqrt 2) * x, so no singularities. Multiplying both sides by y, then substituting y*y=v yielded a similar interesting differential equation.

Comment: The substitution $t=y/x, r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ gives $dr(t^2+1)(r-t)=dt(r+tr^2)$ which at least lacks a square-root.

Comment: @Empy2 At least you convert the ODE to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [To solve $ \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786260):

Apply the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

Let $u=y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{2u}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{u}$

$\therefore\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{u}=u-\left(\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{2u}\right)$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{u}=\dfrac{u}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u}$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{u}{2}+\dfrac{x^2+2x}{2u}$

$(u^2+x^2)\dfrac{du}{dx}=u^3+(x^2+2x)u$

Let $v=u^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2u\dfrac{du}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u^2+x^2}{2u}\dfrac{dv}{dx}=u^3+(x^2+2x)u$

$(u^2+x^2)\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2u^4+(2x^2+4x)u^2$

$(v+x^2)\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2v^2+(2x^2+4x)v$

Let $w=v+x^2$ ,

Then $v=w-x^2$

$\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dw}{dx}-2x$

$\therefore w\left(\dfrac{dw}{dx}-2x\right)=2(w-x^2)^2+(2x^2+4x)(w-x^2)$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dx}-2xw=2w^2+(4x-2x^2)w-4x^3$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dx}=2w^2+(6x-2x^2)w-4x^3$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $w=\dfrac{1}{z}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{dz}{dx}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{z^3}\dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{2}{z^2}+\dfrac{6x-2x^2}{z}-4x^3$

$\dfrac{dz}{dx}=4x^3z^3+(2x^2-6x)z^2-2z$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Comment: Thank you doraemonnpaul. Apparently, from your citation, this class of equation was considered unsolvable until 2011. I was a math major 40 years ago,  before entering the field of medicine. Differential equations have always remained a hobby of mine, especially nonlinear. This particular equation has fascinated me for the last few years. Thank you so much for your expertise in providing the solution.