# Differential Equation $ \frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(\sqrt{y^2 + x^2}) $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(\sqrt{y^2 + x^2}) $
I can't solve this ODE, no Idea on what to do, posted yesterday one similar, however this is the one answering to a problem

Comment: What exactly is your task? Is it really to solve this equation symbolically, or is it to determine some properties of this ODE?

Comment: What does "however this is the one answering to a problem" mean?

Comment: Doesn't an ODE normally come with an initial condition?

Comment: Only hope with numerics.

Comment: Is there any way of using a change of coordinates?

Comment: Sorry for answering late!

@ViktorGlombik last ODE I asked for wasn't the one I was looking for, this is the one. I'm not looking for a function specifically but the family of functions with "this" property or with this DE

Comment: @LutzL Solve this equation symbolically

Comment: @HenryLee Haven't tried

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk how would the result look like?

Comment: Approximation look like: `y(x)=8/100*x + 65/100 x^3` in range `-1..1`,using initial condition: `y(0)=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Similar to [$dy/dx=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886515):

Apply the [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution):

Let $u=y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{2u}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{u}$

$\therefore\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2u^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{x}{u}=\tan\left(u-\left(\dfrac{u}{2}-\dfrac{x^2}{2u}\right)\right)$

$\dfrac{u^2+x^2}{2u^2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{x}{u}+\tan\dfrac{u^2+x^2}{2u}$

$(u^2+x^2)\dfrac{du}{dx}=2xu+2u^2\tan\dfrac{u^2+x^2}{2u}$

Comment: I haven't even taken calculus class, so I don't know how to proceed from here,however it looks a bit nicer. What could I do here?